# wcf service initialisation

Tags: wcf, parameters, constructor

I have a service that is simply wrapping a component methods.
I create the service programmatically and I need to initialize it with the component (either pass in as a parameter in the constructor, have setter method, or any way). My service is self-hosted in a windows service. I read about IInstanceProvider and ServiceHost aproach, however I think that's probably more used for DI containers and what I need to do should be much more simple.
Any advise would be appreciated. Here's my sample code:

1. Programmatically creating the service:

   ```
   _plcServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PLCService));


       foreach (var plc in PLCRepository.GetAllLocal())
       {
           var baseAddress = plc.LocalEndpointName;

           var binding = new NetTcpBinding();

           _plcServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPLCService), binding, baseAddress);


           AddMetadataExchange(_plcServiceHost, baseAddress);
       }

   _plcServiceHost.Open();
   ```

This is how I would like to have my service (2a or 2b).
2a. PLC Service with setter:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class PLCService : IPLCService
    {
        #region fields
        public static volatile object HardwareLock = new object();
        private IPLCImpl _plc;
        private Semaphore _unsubscribeSem;
        private bool _isSubscribed;

        #endregion

        public void SetPLC(IPLCImpl plc)
        {
            if (plc == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("plc");

            _plc = plc;

            _plc.Connect();
        }
```

2b. PLC Service with initialization on constructor:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class PLCService : IPLCService
    {
        #region fields
        public static volatile object HardwareLock = new object();
        private readonly IPLCImpl _plc;
        private Semaphore _unsubscribeSem;
        private bool _isSubscribed;

        #endregion

        public PLCService(IPLCImpl plc)
        {
            if (plc == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("plc");

            _plc = plc;

            _plc.Connect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can init the implementation from outside of your service, using mentioned DI like Unity, Castle, and so on.

In this way, you can just use it in `PLCService` constructor.